# Order of the symplectic group over $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: local-rings, symplectic-group

Let $p$ be a prime number and $q$ some power of it. It is well-known that the order of the symplectic group $\text{Sp}_{2g}(\mathbb{F}_q)$ over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ equals $q^{g^2}\prod_{i=1}^g(q^{2i}-1)$.

Is there (a similar) expression for the order of the finite group scheme $\text{Sp}_{2g}(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})$? What if we replace $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ by $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for any integer $n$?